# How to only limit length for user input but let any length to be entered programatically

Tags: html, angular

In this scenario the input field is limited to 5 Characters for the user to enter, once the user enters the 5 characters I append programatically a kind of description for the input to it (USER-Description).

Since the actual input will be the users input i want that to be limited to 5 but I should be able to programatically add a string of any length. When I do this currently the input field stays Red as if the required flag is on.

Comment: You can't "sort of" limit the length. You either limit it, or you don't.  you don't need the input to be able to store the value programmatically - You can use a variable instead (For example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below points may help

1. You can add a empty box and maxLength Validation on (**focus**). and on (**blur**) remove the validation and apeend extra text.

or

2. you can do via css Trick, make a **input group box**. (input + div). (search input-group bootstrap for more info).
   Have input a validation of 5 charter in input box and on focus and blur play with your append logic.

- point 1 code will look something like this

> ```
>  <input type="text"
>            (focus)="firstName.maxLength = 5"
>                     (blur)="appendString()"
>      name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="model.firstName" #firstName="ngModel" required />
> ```

Comment: So i ended up having a variable bound to [maxlength] which i manipulate in onFocus by setting to the maxLength I want and onBlur i set it to 100. turns out the input box turning red was due to the ngClass I have set for invalid inputs [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': invalid }" . If you dont have a invalid class implemented like this for a normal input the issue shouldnt be there.